# how to convert XML to Collection and iterate based on the indexing? as I need to further perform operation on the collection in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring

I need to filter and aggregate the nodes having same value in a xml file using the java code.

In the below code, i need to aggregate and write the details of students having  same gender in different files.

`enter code here`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<student> 
   <name>aaa</name>  
   <gender>M<gender> 
   <Address>
     <City>Auckland</City>
     <Zipcode>2310`enter code here`</Zipcode>
    </Address>
<student/> 
<student>  
  <name>bbb</name> 
  <gender>f</gender> 
  <Address>
     <City>Wellington</City>
     <Zipcode>2310</Zipcode>
    </Address>

</student> 
<student>  
  <name>ccc</name>  
  <gender>f</gender>
  <Address>
     <City>NorthIsland</City>
     <Zipcode>5671</Zipcode>
    </Address>
</student>
```

This is the current parser code. I am unable to print distinct values. I tried using hashset but no luck.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
         try {
              List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();

            File file = new File("/Downloads/student.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);
     
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Student com= (Student) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            
        //  ArrayList<Student> list=(ArrayList<Student>) com.getStudent();
            List<Student> list = com.getStudent();
            for(Student stu:list) {
    
            student.add(new Student(stu.getFirstName()+" "+stu.getLastName()+" "+stu.getContactNo()+" "+stu.getGender()+" "+stu.getGender());
            }


        List<Employee> newList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output

```
John Green 1234567890 m
```

Need to check for the distinct records. This is not printing the distinct values.

```
List<Student> newList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @BasilBourque a) I need to read the XML. b) Need to write the student data based on their gender in different text files. 

I am able to parse XML but unable to find the logic to iterate and compare gender values so that I could put gender with 'f' in one file and gender with 'm' in another file.

Comment: @newtoJava   Can you share your parser code? And also once parsed, what you are getting as output? as list of just Student object

Comment: @AshishPatil I have added the snippet. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as per comments & question it looks like you need to do below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
           
     try {
 
        File file = new File("/Downloads/student.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);
 
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Student com= (Student) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        List<Student> list = com.getStudent();
        list.stream().forEach(stu->{
         if(stu.getGender().equalsIgnoreCase("M")){
          //write to file where Male gender details can be stored.
           
          }
         else {
          //write to file where Male gender details can be stored.
         }
         });
        
        }
     }}
```

Here, you can obtain stream & compare each element & write to your respective files element by element.

Please note, you can declare your files at beginning of `main`.

Edit: As you are looking for multilevel grouping then below is what I am suggesting:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Student>>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.getGender(), Collectors.groupingBy(y -> y.getAddress().getZipCode())));
```

This map has aggregation of data based on gender and zip. Iterate this map & put details into different files.

Comment: Wonderful. It worked. I further need to segregate records based on the zip code. I believe this code won't work for this.

Comment: You mean gender & zip ? it can work with little modifications, but let me know if you need both gender & zip segregation together

Comment: Moreover, can you please upvote & accept answer in meanwhile?

Comment: yes, I need zipcode segregation as well. Updated the xml.

Comment: Do you need to have different zip based details in separate files? lets say, you separated data based on gender, now you want to separate based on zip but how you would want to store?

Comment: In the different text files of segregated area/zip code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am trying to check for the duplicate data. But it's not printing the desired result. code added.

Comment: @newtoJava, can you please create new question & share link to me so that I can check because your latest edit looks new question to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72858057/unable-to-print-distinct-values-from-list-of-object-type-in-java 
Please check @AshishPatil

Comment: Can you confirm you need distinction based on which field? your question is quite confusion

Comment: @newtoJava , just shared answer in general, please consider accepting answer if it is ok for you.