# Unable to print distinct values from list of object type in java

Tags: java, xml

Unable to print distinct values from list of object type in java. This is my current parser code and am checking for the duplicate values.

In the below code I am trying to fetch unique values from newList.

XML - sample

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <student> 
       <fname>aaa</fname> 
       <lname>aaa</lname>  
     
       <gender>M<gender> 
       <Address>
         <City>Auckland</City>
         <Zipcode>2310`enter code here`</Zipcode>
        </Address>
    <student/> 
    <student>  
    <fname>abc</fname> 
       <lname>aaa</lname>  
    <gender>f</gender> 
      <Address>
         <City>Wellington</City>
         <Zipcode>2310</Zipcode>
        </Address>
    
    </student> 
    <student>  
    <fname>aaa</fname> 
       <lname>aaa</lname>  
    <gender>f</gender>
      <Address>
         <City>NorthIsland</City>
         <Zipcode>5671</Zipcode>
        </Address>
    </student>
</company>
```

Below is the student pojo class and similarly there is one address pojo class having addrress details and Company class having list of students

```
public class Student {
            private String FirstName;
            private String LastName;
            private String Gender;
            private List<Address> address;
            public Object student;

            
            
            public Student() {}
            public Student(String FirstName, String LastName, String Gender,List<Address> address) {
            super();
                this.FirstName = FirstName;
            .
            .
            .
            .   
            
            }
            
            getters/setter
            
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                 return "<" + FirstName + ", " + LastName + ", " + Gender + ", " + address +  ">";
            }
            
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(student);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        student other = (student) obj;
        return  Objects.equals(student, other.student);
    }
        }
```

```java
    

public static void main(String[] args) {
             try {
                  List<Student> student = new ArrayList<Student>();
    
                File file = new File("/Downloads/student.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);
         
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                Student com= (Student) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
                
                List<Student> list = com.getStudent();
                for(Student stu:list) {
        
                student.add(new Student(stu.getFirstName()+" "+stu.getLastName()+" "+stu.getContactNo()+" "+stu.getGender());
                }
    
    
            List<Student> newList = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
         System.out.println(newList);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear and you're casting Student to Employee which I guess is a mistake. But generally speaking I think you want to filter distinct students and you don't manage to do it. So my quetion: did you implement equals and hashCode for the class Student?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What is not working?  Creating the list of distinct objects ... or printing the list?   I note that the code you showed us doesn't even attempt to print the list.

Comment: @StephenC I think he expects two Student instances having the same fields to be equal, but they're not because he didn't implement equals and hashCode in the Student class. Also, I don't think the code is a reproducible example but just some copy paste (the collected list is of Employee, not of Student, I think he randomly copied some test variables)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - It does not matter what you think the OP is asking.  What matters is what the OP is *actually* asking.  (Besides, if that is what this is really asking, then this is simply a dup of thousands of other questions.  And should be closed as a dup.)

Comment: @StephenC agree with all you said. But I'm pretty sure that's it (he's also talking about using Set instead of List to remove duplicates)

Comment: @StephenC I have updated my code and query. Hope this is understandable right now. I am new to the platform.

Comment: @newtoJava , refer my code & generate `equals` & `hashcode` from your editor for `Student`. You should be able to get distinct vals

Comment: OK ... so Matteo guessed correctly.  And the problem is that you need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `Student` class ... so that `HashSet` has the correct notion of what equality means for the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your `Student` class has name & sex fields, then to use `distinct()` of streams you have to override `equals` , something like below:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String sex;
    // getters & setters
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, sex);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        return Objects.equals(name, other.name) && Objects.equals(sex, other.sex);
    }
}
```

Then while using list:

```
 Student stu= new Student();
    stu.setName("A");
    stu.setSex("M");
    Student stu1= new Student();
    stu1.setName("B");
    stu1.setSex("F");
    Student stu2= new Student();
    stu2.setName("C");
    stu2.setSex("F");
    Student stu3= new Student();
    stu3.setName("A");
    stu3.setSex("M");
    List<Student> list =new ArrayList<Student>();
    System.out.println(list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

will give you 3 records instead of 4 as one `Student` object is duplicate as per `equals`.

So please check if you have `equals` method present in your POJO & if it is not, then please have one & then use `distict` within streams.

Comment: Just Curious. Is there any way where we could find distinct on the entire List<Student> i.e
John Green 1234567890 m ;
John Santo 9999999999 m ;
John Green 1234567890 m ;. Hope you're getting my question.

Comment: Yup, in your Java editor, go to `Employees` class & right click & search for source. That will give you ready-made `equals` & `hashcode` method for `Employee`. Once you use it, your `distinct` will work as expected.

Comment: Now it's only printing single record but there are more records in the input

Comment: You are keep changing your POJO between `Employee` & `Student` . Can you just check what I have shared as answer & use it to your POJO. It should work

Comment: I have updated the student pojo code

Comment: Your `equals` is wrong; please recheck